# google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Received RST_STREAM with error code 2

Tags: grpc, recaptcha, grpc-python, recaptcha-enterprise

When using the create_assessment function in Python from https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment-website#create-assessment-Python an error occurs google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Received RST_STREAM with error code 2

It is interesting to note that on my MacBook it works as it should, the error occurs only on the server (Ubuntu 20.04)

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1161, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1004, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INTERNAL
        details = "Received RST_STREAM with error code 2"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2023-10-11T14:54:43.453451939+03:00", grpc_status:13, grpc_message:"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/main20.py", line 70, in <module>
    x = create_assessment(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/main20.py", line 35, in create_assessment
    response = client.create_assessment(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/recaptchaenterprise_v1/services/recaptcha_enterprise_service/client.py", line 646, in create_assessment
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 77, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Received RST_STREAM with error code 2
```

Authorization via (if suddenly this is important):
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./key.json"

I tried changing key.json, tried creating a new Ubuntu 20.04 server. The error remains. But it works on my MacBook.

Comment: does the server have any http(s) proxy?